# Display Searched Values

Tags: php, search

I trying to create a php page where you can search a database on multiple given points 
I've written the search part but I cant figure out how I can display the found items 
so far my code is

```
<html>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<?php
 $connectie = mysql_connect('localhost','root','usbw');
 if($connectie == false){echo "error";}

 if(mysql_select_db('makelaars',$connectie) == false){ echo "error2";}
 ?>
 <table>
<tr>
    <td width= 100>
        Soort Object: 
    </td>
    <td>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method='post'>
    <select name="soort">
        <?php
            $query_soort = "SELECT DISTINCT `Soort_object` FROM `objecten`";
            $resultaat = mysql_query($query_soort, $connectie);
            $inhoud_soort = $_POST['blog'];
        while ($soort = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultaat)) {
            echo "<option>" . htmlentities($soort['Soort_object']) . "</option>";
        }   
        ?>
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <p>Status:</p>
    </td>
    <td>
    <select name="soort">
        <?php
            $query_status = "SELECT DISTINCT `status` FROM `objecten`";
            $resultaatstatus = mysql_query($query_status, $connectie);
            $inhoud_status = $_POST['blog'];
        while ($status = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultaatstatus)) {
            echo "<option>" . htmlentities($status['status']) . "</option>";
        }   
        ?>
    </select>
    </td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <p>Provincie:</p>
    </td>
    <td>
    <select name="provincie">
        <?php
            $query_provincie = "SELECT DISTINCT `Provincie` FROM `objecten`";
            $resultaatprovincie = mysql_query($query_provincie, $connectie);
            $inhoud_provincie = $_POST['blog'];
        while ($provincie = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultaatprovincie)) {
            echo "<option>" . htmlentities($provincie['Provincie']) . "</option>";
        }   
        ?>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" value="verstuur" name="soortknop">
    </td>

</tr>
<tr>

    <td>

    </td>
    </form>
```

can someone please explain to how i could display the data that has the same values that came out of the search

Comment: Might need some elaboration.  Are you asking what to do once the search has happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have not had the chance to test this properly, but it should more or less work. Do take a look at the comments in the code, you've one error (name of a 'select' tag) that will show an error after running this if not fixed!

Put this after you've connected to the database. What you're doing is basically checking whether the submit button was clicked (the $_POST attribute corresponding to the name of the submit button is then set). If it wasn't submitted, the code will simply not execute and results won't be displayed.

I'd also advise you not to use mysql_ functions, but rather look into a library such as PDO. Its parametrized queries make your scripts a lot more secure and prevent SQL injection.

```
<?php

// Submit button was clicked
if(isset($_POST['soortknop'])) {

    // Sanitize data
    $post_soort = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['soort']);
    $post_status = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']); // changed this, you've two select fields 'soort'?
    $post_provincie = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['provincie']);

    // Fetch results using all $post_ variables
    $result_query = mysql_query(
        "SELECT *
        FROM 'objecten'
        WHERE Soort_object = '" . $post_soort . "'
            AND status = '" . $post_status . "'
            AND Provincie = '" . $post_provincie . "'");

    // Display results
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_query)) {
        echo htmlentities($row['Soort_object']) . " " . htmlentities($row['status']) . " " . htmlentities($row['post_provincie ']);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it gives me an error telling me that there is something wrong with the query

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_query))

Comment: You're correct :) It seems I was missing a closing apostrophe! Check the edited code, now it has `$post_provincie . "'");`

Comment: I am still getting the same error sorry to trouble you again but i cant figure out what else could be wrong

Comment: It's no problem. Try removing the quotes from the table name, leaving `FROM objecten`

Comment: That got rid of the error but now when i hit the button it doesnt show me anything

Comment: Maybe there are no rows that meet the criteria? To debug this you could add an `$sql = ` just before the query string, like this: `$result_query = mysql_query($sql = "SELECT *...");` and then before the while loop, do an `echo $sql;` to see the output.

Comment: It just shows me the query for example SELECT Soort_object FROM objecten WHERE Soort_object = 'Woonboot' AND status = 'Te huur' AND Provincie = 'Noord-Holland' which i know exists

Comment: I have edited the answer. In the while loop, we are assigning `$row` to be the row being accessed in every iteration. Basically all the attributes from that row are then stored in `$row`. Hence to access them you write `$row['attribute_name']`. Change the variables in that line to `$row`, like in the answer.

Comment: It now finds the first two items but not the third one also if i want to add a few more values that are in the database like a collum named plaats how would i do that

Comment: It should definitely find all the items. The `while` loop goes through all rows, not leaving out any of them. Make sure you entered the text correctly. As for the columns, do you have a database administration tool such as phpMyAdmin installed? I'm assuming you want a new column in that table. You could add it easily from phpMyAdmin http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/phpmyadmin/adding-a-column-to-a-database-table-in-phpmyadmin

Comment: Okay i made a screenshot of my database http://imgur.com/DJyyx2z and i'm getting this error  Undefined index: post_provincie in G:\USBWebserver v8\root\Makelaars\zoekertje.php on line 98

Comment: "Index" refers to the column name. You asked PHP to find a column named "post_province"! The `$post_` were all VARIABLE names. When you supply something to `$row`, such as `$row['soort']` in the `while` loop, you want to make the argument exactly the same as the column in the database. Add `Provincie` instead, like this: `$row['Provincie']`.

Comment: Just one last stupid question, how could i get the results posted under each other so i isnt just on long line of text. P.S. I'm really greatfull for your help you really saved my bacon

Comment: These ain't stupid, you're learning after all! To break after every row, add a `"<br>"` before the semi-colon, like this: `echo htmlspecialchars($row['something']) . "<br>";` By the way, I'd be grateful if you marked the answer as Accepted :) Thanks

Comment: Just forgot to ask one more thing i also have some images (or the links to them in my database) how would i display these images the same way i display the other text example of a image link /makelaars/Fotos/object1/foto1.jpg

Comment: You'd do `"<img src='" . $row['url'] . "'>"`